# Why is httpServletRequest.getLocalPort always returns the same value with getServerPort?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications, tcp

So I have this very simple class which extends HttpServlet class and implements the doPost method.

I have this in the doPost method:

```
System.out.println("Remote port:" + httpServletRequest.getRemotePort());
System.out.println("Local port:" + httpServletRequest.getLocalPort());
System.out.println("Server port:" + httpServletRequest.getServerPort());
```

I open up Internet Explorer and Chrome and access this Servlet as fast as I can with both browsers. I get the output:

```
Remote port:51773
Local port:8080
Server port:8080
Remote port:51772
Local port:8080
Server port:8080
```

So I can see that Chrome and Internet Explorer gets different TCP ports from the operating system. ( 773 and 772 ) But why is my application responding to both requests from the same Local Port? Should not TCP create different ports and respond from there?

Also in HeadFirst JSP and Servlets book it says:

> "There's a difference, because although the requests are sent to a
>   single port (where the server is listening, the server turns around
>   and finds a different local port for each thread so that the app can
>   handle multiple clients at the same time"

So why both 8080?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is my application responding to both requests from the same Local Port?

Because that's the way TCP works.

> Should not TCP create different ports and respond from there?

No.

> Also in HeadFirst JSP and Servlets book it says:
>
> "There's a difference, because although the requests are sent to a single port (where the server is listening, the server turns around and finds a different local port for each thread so that the app can handle multiple clients at the same time"

Good reason to avoid the book. This is completely incorrect. All sockets accepted from the same listening socket share its local port number. The server does not 'turn around and find a different local port' for each thread' at all, and this isn't necessary so that 'the app can handle multiple clients at the same time'. This is already guaranteed by TCP.

> So why both 8080?

See above.

This is a surprisingly common misconception about TCP, but a misconception nonetheless.

Comment: I thought a TCP port listening to incoming connections will create a new one and use that for connection, so the given port can continue listening to incoming connections? If you see the code here: http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/ the Socket object is created when ServerSocket.accept() method is invoked. So I am confused now?